# Accessing information about data objects that caused a request to error in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, function, closures, indexeddb

If a request to indexedDB fails, is there a way in the error handler to record information about the data object that wasn't added to the database? I looked for it in the event object but didn't find anything.

In the code below, I'm trying to write data elements `d` from text file `t` back to the object store `s` but don't want the transaction to roll back if one or more data elements error. If there is an error, I want to record the data that failed in the `req_err` array and continue writing the "good" data. The "bad" data will be displayed to the user to correct or discard.

The code below works as it is now, but it seems that there should be a way to do so without making the requests elements of an array and adding properties to the request objects, and then accessing them using `this` in the error event handler.

When the variable `req` was a scalar, the data elements that failed to parse were recorded without issue because the value of the loop counter `i`, which is used as an index to reference data from array `n`, is "current" at the time it is used.  But the data that cause the add request to fail can't use the loop counter as a reference because, by the time the request completes, the loop finished and `i` is equal to `l`, the top value of the loop. The same is true for object `q`.  It is always the last data element in the file at that point. I need something like a closure on the event handlers.

My question is can `i` and `q` be made available to the `req.onerror` event handler without making `req` an array and adding them as properties of it? Or, is there a better way altogether to access them?

Thank you.

```
for ( i = 1; i < l; i++ )
  { 
    d = t.substring( x, x + map[i] ); 
    try
      {
        q = JSON.parse( d  ); 
      }
    catch
      {
        q = { "id" : n[i].key, "data" : "empty data object to be inserted here later" }; 
        req_err[ err_cnt ] = { 'q' : n[i].q, 'key' : n[i].key, 'data' : d, 'error' : "Failed to parse the string to an object." };
        err_cnt = err_cnt + 1;
      }
    finally
      {
        x = x + map[i]; 
      }  

    req[i] = s.add( q ); 
    req[i].i = i;
    req[i].q = q;


    req[i].onerror = function( event ) 
      {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.stopPropagation();
        req_err[ err_cnt ] = { 'q' : n[this.i].q, 'key' : n[this.i].key, 'data' : this.q, 'error' : event.target.error };
        err_cnt = err_cnt + 1;
      }; // close req.onerror

    req[i].onsuccess = function( event )
      {
        $("#msg").text( 'Processed data element : ' + this.i + ' of ' + l ); 
      };

  }; // next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems that there should be a way to do so without making the requests elements of an array and adding properties to the request objects, and then accessing them using this in the error event handler.

You can avoid the use of the array, but the API doesn't provide the parameters; you do need to stash them yourself - I'd put it on the IDBRequest object - and either use a closure or `this`. Here's how I'd do it:

```
const records = [...];
records.forEach(record => {
  const request = store.put(record);
  request.put_value = record;
  request.onerror = e => {
    console.log(`failed to put: ${request.put_value}: ${e.message}`);
  };
});
```